# Ip address compare in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to solve a problem that could compare 2 columns in a table.
the table is as follows

```
------------------------------------------
|  from    |    to           |  Country  |
------------------------------------------
| 25.0.0.1 | 25.255.255.255  |  denmark  |
------------------------------------------
| 68.0.0.1 | 68.255.255.255  |  USA      |
```

---

My problem is i have a  ip of `25.195.32.0` and i want to compare this to the `from` and `to` column and return the `country name`.

Comment: You mean within it's range?

Comment: You can use ip2long() to convert and compare the ip's http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Comment: Following the comment from Mattt. In case you want to make this comparison more often, it might be helpful to store the long equivalent of `from` and `to` in two extra columns to enhance performance of your query.

Comment: Just a suggestion might be using some sort of geoip instead of some homebrewed geoip if thats what you are looking to do. Also you might want to change your `from` because its a reserved word in MySQL.

Comment: Also, this is the sort of thing that would be much more cleanly stored as a network/subnet mask than an IP address range. Postgres handles that as a built-in type; not sure about MySQL.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `INET_ATON` to get a numeric value of the IPs to compare.

```
SELECT country FROM table
WHERE INET_ATON('25.195.32.0') BETWEEN INET_ATON(from) AND INET_ATON(to)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

Comment: +1 on finding / using `INET_ATON()`, seems to be the MYSQL equivalent of PHP's `IP2LONG()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find using `IN()` try condition according you use `AND` or `OR`

```
WHERE from IN('your_ip') OR to IN('your_ip')
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform IP into integer, then compare integer is simple. MySQL offers the `inet_aton` function to do so.

```
select Country from table_name where inet_aton($ip) between inet_aton(`from`) and inet_aton(`ip`);
```

For performance, you should transform column `from`, `to` to integer manully. eg. add to columns `from_n`, `to_n`. then your SQL will be like this:

```
select Country from table_name where inet_aton($ip) between `from_n` and `to_n`
```

If you are not using MySQL, you should transform `$ip` into integer $ip_n first (using something like Python's `socket.inet_aton`), then replace `inet_aton($ip)` with `$ip_n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from db.table
```

Then in php (assuming you've run the quest and stored results):

```
$lookupIP;

for($i=0;$i<$db->getRowCount();$i++) {
    $partsFROM = explode(".", $FROM);
    $partsTO = explode(".", $TO);
    $partsLOOKUP = explode(".",$lookupIP);
    if(
        $partsLOOKUP[0] >= $partsFROM[0] && $partsLOOKUP[0] <= $partsTO[0]  
     && $partsLOOKUP[1] >= $partsFROM[1] && $partsLOOKUP[1] <= $partsTO[1]  
     && etc..
    ) return $Country
}
```

Not particularly efficient or elegant but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

As i interpret from the question, you can use some mask and get the base ip address and then compare it. To use the mask and get base ip, you need to learn something about different classes (A, B, C, D) used from addressing.

Refer this link http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Answer (score 1):

`INET_ATON` gives desired solution on `IPV4` addresses.

Apart from that, you can also try `HEX` version of the IP to compare in between.

```
SELECT  HEX( input_ip_value ) 
BETWEEN HEX( from_ip_column ) 
    AND HEX( to_ip_column )
```

**Example**:

```
mysql> select @i:=hex('25.195.32.0'),
    -> @f:=hex('25.0.0.1'),
    -> @t:=hex('25.255.255.255'),
    -> @i between @f and @t is_between;
+------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------------+
| @i:=hex('25.195.32.0') | @f:=hex('25.0.0.1') | @t:=hex('25.255.255.255')    | is_between |
+------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------------+
| 32352E3139352E33322E30 | 32352E302E302E31    | 32352E3235352E3235352E323535 |          1 |
+------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Select a range:

```
SELECT Country FROM table_name WHERE ip_address >= from AND to <= ip_address
```

If you can use a script (eg php) you could select the entire table and make a mask to the IP. Something like:

> We can know what belongs to the network address 192.168.129.3/18 ip as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> ip_en_binario = decbin (ip2long ("192.168.129.3")); 
> mascara_en_binario = decbin (ip2long ("255.255.192.0")); 
> resultado_en_binario $ = $ & $ mascara_en_binario ip_en_binario; 
> miss long2ip (bindec ($ resultado_en_binario));
> ```
>
> The result returned us this script is 192.168.128.0, which is the network address to which the IP belongs 192.168.129.3/18.

Then, you can do a 'SELECT' of your network with "from" and "to" fields.

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
select Country from table_name where from=to;
```

Comment: No. this is not a valid answer. from and to are a range of values. You should check if input is within that range.

Comment: I'm guessing he/she means return the country who's range includes the input: i.e. 25.195.32.0 -> denmark